# Where are wine's dll files located? I need to put vox.dll in the path?

Tags: wine

Where are wine's dll files located?

I need to add vox.dll file to the path.

I got the error message `dll file is missing`

But I found a program including the vox.dll file.

[image: Vox.dll file in .wine/drive_c/Program Files/Kakao/KakaoTalk]

Comment: can you name the program/apps require that specific dlls ?

Comment: https://hiseon.me/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-kakaotalk/